# Reading environment variables in SymmetricDS engine properties

Tags: environment-variables, build.gradle, symmetricds

I'm using the [Gradle Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) to create a zip distribution of SymmetricDS. It would be nice to have a simple way of switching between environments (test, staging, production, whatever).

The [SymemtricDS User Guide](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html#_standalone_installation) says

```
SymmetricDS will automatically create a node for each Node Properties
File configured in the engines directory
```

So, it will probably not be possible to define engines for all environments and choose which one to start, without doing this manually.

A better way would probably be to have SymmetricDS read some environment variables and use these to define e.g. `db.url` in the engine files. This way the same config could be used for all environments. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been several requests for something like this.  I noticed someone setting up docker images also would benefit from being able to specify dynamic properties.  I'm adding the ability to do token replacement with environment variable or system properties in 3.8.12.

Here is the issue to track it: https://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2945

Comment: Nice. If this becomes available for all properties, it would make it much easier to set ports dynamically in sync.url and registration.url in order to easily running multiple instances (possibly at the same host) in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gradle Resource filtering](https://dzone.com/articles/resource-filtering-gradle) to replace variable placeholders in your `symmetric-ds.properties` file. For example

```
db.url=${env.db.url}
db.user=${env.db.user}
db.password=${env.db.password}
```

then create as many config files as there are environments where the actual values of placeholders would be saved, for example `dev.conf`:

```
env.db.url=jdbc://db_host:1520
env.db.user=my_user
env.db.user=p4$$vv0rd
```

use a command line parameter to choose an environment to `gradle assembly` command which will choose one of conf files

Comment: Thanks. We solved our problem by Dockerizing the thing and using good 'ol sed to overwrite the variables in the .properties files on startup based on ENV variables given to the Docker container. This way we don't need a separate build per environment. With this solution this is the case, correct?

Comment: It's another approach resulting in the same outcome

Comment: Where would the dev.conf file go? Can you be more specific as to how I would implement this in a typical SymmetricDS setup?